# How to make RestSharp return my custom RestResponse

Tags: c#, restsharp

The standard `RestClient` found in the RestSharp project has an `Execute()` method that looks like this:

```
public virtual RestSharp.IRestResponse Execute(RestSharp.IRestRequest request)
```

I can create a custom request class and feed it to this method, as long as my request implements the proper interface.

```
public class MyRestRequest : IRestRequest
{
}
```

Now suppose I want to map requests of type `MyRestRequest` to responses of type `MyRestResponse`:

```
public class MyRestRequest : IRestResponse
{
}
```

How would I go about telling the client to create an instance of my response class instead of the default `RestResponse`? Can I not do this without having to override the `Execute()` procedure?

**EDIT**

To clarify: `RestClient.Execute()` is hard-coded to **always** return an instance of `RestResponse`.

Source (line 64): https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.Sync.cs

I've posted this issue on their [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/A8akkc5ViMk) board, but the project looks pretty much dead to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just cast the IRestReponse to MyRestRequest, eg:

```
MyRestResponse response = (MyRestResponse)client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right... casting would require `RestResponse` to be a descendant of `MyRestResponse`, when in fact the opposite is true. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't implement custom cast support between types in the same inheritance tree either. :-/